# How to make code say 'invalid input' when a user enters a character or a string (Validate)

Tags: c, validation

I'm new to c and i just wanted to know how to make my code say ' invalid input' if they decide to enter a character or gibberish.

My code is just a simple Celsius to Kelvin (i know very simple) and i just adds 273 to any inputted number. i tried to use isdidgit but it was unsuccessful.

My code;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int temp = 273;
int cel;
int cel2;
int choice;

    switch (choice)
{
case 1:
printf("enter ce to conv to kel: ");
scanf("%ld", &cel);
cel2 = cel + temp;          
printf("%d in Celsuis is: %d Kelvin \n", cel, cel2)
```

I accept all feedback / improvements,
thanks 
~Neamus

Comment: `isdigit` works for a single character. You should read input as a string and use `strtol` to convert, so you can handle the bad input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presently, your code has no way to recover from an invalid input.  That is, if a user enters `"a"` when prompted, `scanf()` will never return because it will be waiting for a base-10 integer value.

What you will need to do is read the input as a C-string and process that:

```
char input[80];
do {
    printf("enter ce to conv to kel: ");
    scanf("%79[^\n]\n", input); // read until newline; toss newline
} while (input_is_bad(input)); // your function to validate input
cel = atoi(input); // atoi parses C-string, returning an int
cel2 = cel + temp;
printf("%d in Celsuis is: %d Kelvin \n", cel, cel2);
```

Inside your own `input_is_bad()` function, you can print a message stating that the input is not valid.

Comment: @TaohidulIslam In that case, `input` would only contain the null character.  I assume that would be an invalid input.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `fgets` and `strtol`. See the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int temp = 273;
int cel;
int cel2;
int choice;
int flag;
char *p, str[100];

    printf("enter ce to conv to kel: ");
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)) {
        cel = strtol(str, &p, 10); //number of base 10
        if (p == str || *p != '\n') {
            printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        }
        else break; //if input is integer then break the loop
    }
//do your calculations here

    return 0;
}
```